# Ninject Context for GetScope method

Tags: c#, ninject

I have an application where I have an Ninject binding with a singleton scope. It's important that this service is always a singleton, so I'd like to write a unit test to make sure it's never modified.

My test is as follows:

```
// Arrange
var kernel = new StandardKernel(new AgentModule());

// Act
var pushBrokerBindings = kernel.GetBindings(typeof(IPushBroker)).ToList();

// Assert
pushBrokerBindings.ForEach(binding => Assert.That(binding.GetScope(**What IContext**), Is.InstanceOf<**SingletonScopeClass**>()))
```

When I have the binding, I would like to get the scope of the IPushBroker and assert that it's in a Singleton scope, but I'm not sure where I get the IContext parameter for the GetScope method?

My binding is declared as:

```
Bind<IPushBroker>().To<PushBroker>().InSingletonScope();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Wouldn't `ReferenceEquals` suffice?

Comment: I'm not having a problem checking the reference, I'm having a problem getting the reference to check. I don't know what IContext to pass to GetScope.

Comment: I would suggest that this is something _not_ to unit test. Spec Tests should cover this. The spec test would usually not specifically test this exactly, even though it could.
Since there is a reason why this needs to be singleton, verify that the system meets that condition(s).